# Prevent from Downloading same file multiple times

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, html

I'm using below script to show loading gif while the file is ready to download and then Once it is done , it hides after couple of seconds. 
But I Only want to dowanload the file once, but when I click the link it download the same file twice. I found the code somewhere in forums, so I really don't know how to prevent it from running the url twice.

```js
   $(".file a").on("click",function(e){
  var originalHtml=$(this).html();
    $(this).html('<div class="load-container load8"><div class="loader">Loading...</div></div>'); // do your UI thing here
    e.preventDefault();
    var destination = this.href;
    var clickedLink=$(this);
    setTimeout(function() {
      clickedLink.html(originalHtml);
        window.location = destination;

    },2500);
    $('<iframe>').hide().appendTo('body').load(function() {
        window.location =sagar;
    }).attr('sagar', sagar);
});
```

```css
.loader,
.loader:before,
.loader:after {
  border-radius: 50%;
  width: 2.5em;
  height: 2.5em;
  -webkit-animation-fill-mode: both;
  animation-fill-mode: both;
  -webkit-animation: load7 1.8s infinite ease-in-out;
  animation: load7 1.8s infinite ease-in-out;
}
.loader {
  color: darkblue;
  font-size: 10px;
  margin: 80px auto;
  position: relative;
  text-indent: -9999em;
  -webkit-transform: translateZ(0);
  -ms-transform: translateZ(0);
  transform: translateZ(0);
  -webkit-animation-delay: -0.16s;
  animation-delay: -0.16s;
}
.loader:before,
.loader:after {
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
}
.loader:before {
  left: -3.5em;
  -webkit-animation-delay: -0.32s;
  animation-delay: -0.32s;
}
.loader:after {
  left: 3.5em;
}
@-webkit-keyframes load7 {
  0%,
  80%,
  100% {
    box-shadow: 0 2.5em 0 -1.3em;
  }
  40% {
    box-shadow: 0 2.5em 0 0;
  }
}
@keyframes load7 {
  0%,
  80%,
  100% {
    box-shadow: 0 2.5em 0 -1.3em;
  }
  40% {
    box-shadow: 0 2.5em 0 0;
  }
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<body style="color: black;  background-color: #EFF6E4;font-family: myFirstFont; ">



   <ol class="tree">
    
    <li>
      <label for="folder1">First Semester</label> <input type="checkbox" id="folder1" /> 
      <ol>
        
        <li>
          <label for="subfolder11">Classical Mechanics </label> <input type="checkbox" id="subfolder11" /> 
          <ol>
            
            <li class="file"><a href="https://drive.google.com/uc?export=download&id=1Q2Sr1ouPQ_P-i48tlRxcGctiMtlIbBwX">Solutions_to_Problems_in_Goldstein)</a></li>
            <li class="file"><a href="https://drive.google.com/uc?export=download&id=1GxWkj_oevSmxHFp4rDrNbvM5kBTaJ31B">Goldstein Solution Chapter 8 Soln</a></li>
<li class="file"><a href=" https://drive.google.com/uc?export=download&id=1f9wJftmvaI-B_jpYXPIk1rTbiHOJ-BzU">Goldstein Chapter 9 Soln</a></li>
            <li class="file"><a href=" https://drive.google.com/uc?export=download&id=1OXoTG3GmY3EhNBnPhXID4hHxzJUN-tGb">Numericals Jacobi Angle ( Hints )</a></li>
              <li class="file"><a href="https://drive.google.com/uc?export=download&id=1nD3ChGK-sMNpXbXXT394Fgu0xS1_aa35">Angle Jacobi Numericals ( Complete Solution)</a></li>
          </ol>
      </li>
  </ol>
</li>
</ol>
</body>
```

Any help would be really appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

It seems you are calling `window.location = destination;` (which is triggering the browser to download the file) twice, inside that `setTimeout` function and after a hidden iframe is loaded, which I think is the correct place.

Just stop calling `setTimeout` like below:

```
$(".file a").on("click",function(e){
  var originalHtml=$(this).html();
    $(this).html('<div class="load-container load8"><div class="loader">Loading...</div></div>'); // do your UI thing here
    e.preventDefault();
    var destination = this.href;
    var clickedLink=$(this);
    $('<iframe>').hide().appendTo('body').load(function() {
        window.location = destination;
        clickedLink.html(originalHtml);
    }).attr('src', destination);
});
```

Comment: But I want the iframe to hide after the file begin to Download and you solution will show the loading gif forever which I want to hide after certain time or when the download begins.....what doI do now?? any solution?